# Harvard Referencing in Latex

Tags: bibliographies, citing, harvard-style

I am new to LaTeX, just started yesterday.

I want to use Harvard referencing in my thesis. I had googled, do we need install some kind of package? Maybe [`harvard`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/)?

Currently, my `reference.bib` has

```
@book{123,
  title={Rendezvous with Rama},
  author={Clarke, Arthur Charles},
  year={1990},
  publisher={Spectra}
}
```

and my chapter have:

```
\textcite{123}  %for Harvard referencing
\cite{123}
```

Comment: I assume that by "Harvard referencing", you mean creating authoryear-style citation call-outs (as opposed to, say, numeric-style citation call-outs). The `harvard` citation management package and its 6 or 7 associated bibliography styles can indeed be used to create authoryear-style citation call-outs. However, several other packages (including `natbib` and `apacite`, if you want to stay with a "traditional" BibTeX-based tool, or the `biblatex` package) can all be used to create authoryear-style citation call-outs as well. Which bibliography style to choose may be dictated by your university.

Comment: If your TeX distribution is at all standard, the `harvard`, `natbib`, `apacite`, and `biblatex` packages should all be installed by default.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Overleaf.